# Is there a way to automagically group by (almost) all columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Basically I have a dataset which has a large number of columns, and it might even grow in the future.

Now before I analyse the data, in most cases it makes sense to group by all columns. I can manually type everything, I know, but I was wondering if there is a way to make it automatic.

As an example, think of list of invoice items where many attributes actually just further describe the product (data is heavily denormalised), eg:

```
InvoiceId     ProductId    Price   CustomerName   SomeOtherProductAttribute...
123           ABC          32.11   CustA          xyz
123           BBB          99.99   CustA          xyzy
444           ABC          32.11   CustB          xyz
444           CCC          12.99   CustB          ttt
```

and I want to summarise the price

```
[,sum(price),by=list(invoiceId,ProductId,CustomerName,SomeOtherProductAttribute)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `setdiff`:

```
DT[, sum(Price), by = setdiff(names(DT), "Price")]
   InvoiceId ProductId CustomerName SomeOtherProductAttribute...    V1
1:       123       ABC        CustA                          xyz 32.11
2:       123       BBB        CustA                         xyzy 99.99
3:       444       ABC        CustB                          xyz 32.11
4:       444       CCC        CustB                          ttt 12.99
```

Comment: surprised `DT[,sum(Price),by=!"Price"]` doesn't work, given the recent update to accept such arguments in `j`.

Comment: Also, use `DT[,.(Price=sum(Price)),by=setdiff(names(DT),"Price")]` if you want the output column to be named `Price` instead of `V1`; not editing this in because OP didn't supply desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ddply` from plyr package

```
library(plyr)
var_group<-colnames(data)[!(colnames(data) %in% "price")]
ddply(data,(var_group),summarise,price_sum=price)
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because you still "manually" type all the names of the grouping columns (and OP is using data.table).